# Constructing Eloquent ORM output with one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm not sure if I've got the right wording in the title, but this is what I'm after:

I've got a 'designs' table and a 'variables' table. It is a one-to-many relationship such that a design has many variables.

How can I get the data as a single json object?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  Finding the the exact data you need or have you found it and are wondering how to return it as json?

Comment: I'm having trouble returning it as a single object. I can retrieve them separately with: `$design = Design::find($id);` and `$variables = Design::find($id)->variables;` but I want them as a single json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the way you are using your relationships.  You are only either getting the `Design` model or a collection of `Variables`, when you need to get both.

This will eager load the variables with the design and return them as json.

```
$data = Design::where('id', $id)->with('variables')->get();
return Response::json($data, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Designs model should be something like this :

```
class Design extends Eloquent {

    public function variables()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Variable');
    }

}
```

Then, your Variables model should be something like :

```
class Variable extends Eloquent {

    public function design()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Design')
    }

}
```

Finally, in whatever route you are using to return this data :

```
$design = Design::with('variables')->first();
return $design->toJson();
```

Check out the top part of [this link](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json)